# action method fires twice on clicking 'Submit' button on Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, model-view-controller, stimulsoft

I have sumbit button for show stimulreport in `Html.BeginForm()`

it is ok in `Firefox` but run twice in `chrome`.

in view

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">@MenuResource.RegisterReport</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
               
                <div class="col-md-6 ">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SemesterId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SemesterId, new SelectList((IEnumerable<CustomSemesterViewModel>)ViewBag.Semester, "Id", "Name"), string.Format(CommonFieldResource.ChooseDrillDown, SemesterResource.Semester), new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SemesterId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   
                    </div>
                </div>
               
                <div class="col-md-12 ">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">@OperationResource.Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
<div id="registerReportViewer" class="direction-ltr">

</div>
```

in script

```
$("#RegisterReportContainer form").submit(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!$(this).valid())
            return false;
      
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("RegisterReport")',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type:'POST',
            beforeSend: function () {
                waiting.showWaiting('@MessageResource.ReportTitle <br/> @MessageResource.ReportWaiting');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                waiting.hideWaiting();
             
                $("#registerReportViewer").html(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                waiting.hideWaiting();
                Swal.fire({
                    title: '@MessageResource.ReportTitle',
                    text: data.Message,
                    type: "error"
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use Jquery, assign id= submitBtn to your button and try this script:

```
 $(document).on("click", "#submitBtn", (function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

.... call you submit function
    }));
```